# WildFly Jboss EAS 7.2 loadtimeweaving issue with Spring 4.2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss7.x, load-time-weaving

We are blocked with this issue, I will try to put it in words below.

Please have a look at the image first or keep it opened in parallel.

Project is an old Ant based project. Using Spring 4.2.4 currently. Configuration is XML-based.

[image: Have a look at how projects are connected first]

Class `XYZProjectSample` is present inside `XYZ.jar` and a non-Spring class file present inside `ABC.war`, say `ABCWarSample.java` like below:

```java
//non -spring outer class
class ABCWarSample {
  
  //spring-based inner class
  @Configurable
  class InnerBean {
    @Autowired
    XYZProjectSample xyzProjectSampleInstance;
  }

  private XYZProjectSample getService() {
    return new InnerBean().xyzProjectSampleInstance;
  }
}
```

For combining these two classes from different modules, load time weaving is used.

Inside `ABC.war` project's `spring-context.xml` file they have used load time weaving via

```xml
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>
```

1. Now this above line is giving error with Jboss EAP 7.2 as mentioned [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4979191).

   They mentioned upgrade to Spring 5, we did it but encountered page loading issue. like half content coming without and JS and header.

   They have used `requestDispatcher.include()` method to combine two responses. However we see only one and one is lost and there is no visible able error in the logs.
2. Now point two if we keep the Spring version 4, server doesn't start and gives the same issue, see [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4979191).

   We tried some fixes given on internet but nothing has worked so far.

All I am looking for as of now is an alternative of this load time weaving for resolving this dependency. I thought about using compile time weaving, but that requires aspectj-maven plugin and we are using ant scripts.

I am really stuck here. Any advice or alternative solution can be really really helpful.

Please feel free to revert in case of any confusions or if you need more information.

Comment: Please read the rules of the community in order to format your question properly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I completely reformatted your question, please click "edit" (without changing anything) in order to learn how I did it and learn about formatting, e.g. how to use code formatting, syntax highlighting, inline image links, enumerations. Please also make sure that you take care of basic things like upper vs. lower case letters and punctuation in order to keep your postings readable.